# Object cannot have a master-relationship to self. Why?

Tags: custom-object

What is the reasoning behind an object not being able to be the Master-Detail Relationship of its own object?

It is able to have a lookup to its own object, but not a Master-Detail relationship.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By definition, a Child record requires a Parent record.  By allowing a record to be M-D to it's own type, you'd create an infinite loop of parent-child records.

IE:  If you create Record "A" it doesn't have a parent, so you can't create it.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely, the child required a parent record to access.
But if you check the schema of the Standard object account it shows a **self-master-detail relationship.**
It is possible in salesforce but we need extra access.

[image: schema builder image]